# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error when I try to run the application.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages.class

Following are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
    compile project(':backgroundMailLibrary')
}
```

Comment: close your IDE, delete 'build' and `app/build`  folders from your projects directory and then open android studio

Comment: let me try then get back to u

Comment: I did it but still getting the same issue Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages.class

Comment: comment `//` two last dependencies in your `build.gradle` folder and try again

Comment: did it but getting same error

Comment: comment also circlebutton library

Comment: pls help me mate pls

Comment: I have commented that library too but not resolving the issue

Comment: try this mate: Android studio > file > invalidate caches and rebuild again

Comment: No mate it didnt resolve my issue

Comment: What is the result of `gradle androidDependencies`?